# Github: Remove watchers of a repository

Tags: github, repository

I want to remove a specific watcher of my repository in Github. Is there a way to do that?
Or can I even track who's watching my repository?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no way to remove watchers of your repository. When your repository is up on GitHub it becomes public (i.e., anyone can watch/fork it) assuming you have it as a *public* repository.

You can view who is watching your repository by clicking the number beside the *watch/unwatch* icon on the top-right of the repository page.

*If* for some reason it is crucial to remove a specific watcher (and you don't have that many watchers, or this would be a huge pain) you could delete the repository and then recreate it. This should remove any watchers, and start you fresh again. This is a huge pain for *normal* watchers though.

Comment: Can I do the opposite - to add someone as a watcher?

Answer (score 10):

There's currently (as of May 2019) no way to remove a watcher from a specific repository, but you *can* remove a watcher from *all* your repositories (with side effects, detailed below) by blocking and then unblocking them:

1. Navigate to https://github.com/settings/blocked_users
2. Add the watcher in question to your blocked users list
3. Remove them from your blocked users list
4. They'll no longer be listed as watchers on any of your repos

Side effects:

Blocking and unblocking a user will also sever any follower associations you have with them (i.e., if you follow them, you'll have to re-follow, and vice versa)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to remove specific user. But you can remove all watchers by changing visibility of the repo to private then to public again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).